# weird behaviour with BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics

Tags: graphics3d

I see a weird behaviour with BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics. 
When I slightly change the PlotRange option I get a different shape.
Is this a bug?

Below I have included an example that highlight the issue.

```
pad[d_][{min_, max_}] := {min, max} + d (max - min) {-1, 1}

range = {{0.0000554353021`, 2.19994791`},{0.0000505117719`, 2.19987519`},{0.0000218214476`, 3.5994218`}};

plane = HalfSpace[{0.14439585999999993, -0.11945413999999999, 0.1701977600000002},
                  {2.06023755, 1.6676776800000002, 3.26862489}];

{BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[plane,PlotRange -> pad[0.00400001] /@ range],
 BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[plane, PlotRange -> pad[0.004] /@ range],
 BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[plane, PlotRange -> pad[0.00399999] /@ range]}
```

[image: figure]
P.S. This is the first time I ask a question. I apologise if I haven't follow all the rules correctly. The version of Mathematica I use is: Mathematica 12.0.0.0 on Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)

Comment: thanks for spotting it. can you please make a bug report and send it to support@wolfram.com

Comment: Thanks for verifying it. I have submitted a bug report. Now we wait for their response.